# UI Get break after using https

Tags: php, css, ssl, https

I am having a website in php.and is ssl secured
when I try it with http:// it works fine
but when i access it with https:// its UI get break.

I am using this code

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) &&
    ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 1) ||
    isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) &&
    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') {
    $protocol = 'https';
}
else {
    $protocol = 'http';
 }
```

please let me know the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "UI get break" mean? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the console of your browser you'll notice the following errors:

[image: errs]

These errors happen because you are loading over `https`, but requesting resources over `http`, which is not always permitted due to security reasons. When using `https`, you should **load every resource over `https`**.

To solve this you should change the resources links using relative paths, like this:

```
/path/to/resource.css
```

Or serve them on `https`, like this:

```
https://pmiplanet.com/path/to/resource.css
```

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers block insecure content (content served over http)

You'll need to change the links to the CSS and javascript files to https as well:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="http://pmiplanet.com/newTemplate/build/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
<script src="http://pmiplanet.com/newTemplate/build/javascripts/modernizr.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If you change those to something like

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

they will use the same protocol as the parent website (meaning they will use https if you requested the page with https).